# perl grep function

Tags: perl

I am using the perl grep as in the example below. "bfh" is the file handle created by open command for reading.

```
 @searchResults = grep {/,\s*${searchRecId}\s*,\s*${searchSwId}\s*/} <$bfh>;
```

Instead of the file handle "bfh", can I give a filename with path directily, like a unix grep command?  If I want to do it, what change do I need to make?  Is the code below correct?

```
@searchResults = grep {/,\s*${searchRecId}\s*,\s*${searchSwId}\s*/} /tmp/test.out
```

I don't want to give the file handle or array. I just want to do it like a unix grep command.

Will be grepping across 1000 files. When i read a 100000 lines file Each line when it comes to grep i would like to have the file name directly instead of opening 1000 file handles and maintaining in a hashmap.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it through `map`. This snipped, for instance, greps `*.dat` in your current directory:

```
my @searchResults = grep {
    /,\s*${searchRecId}\s*,\s*${searchSwId}\s*/
} map {
    sub {
        my @ret;
        if (open my $fh, "<", shift) {
            @r = <$fh>;
            close @fh;
        }
        return @ret;
    }->($_);
} glob "*.dat";
```

However, this is a suboptimal approach when handling many files with many lines!
Here is a less memory-greedy way of doing the same thing:

```
my @searchResults;
opendir(my $dh, '.') or die "error opening current directory: $!";
while (my $file = readdir $dh) {
    next unless -f $file;
    next if $file !~ /\.dat$/;
    if (open my $fh, '<', $file) {
        while (my $line = <$fh>) {
            if (/,\s*${searchRecId}\s*,\s*${searchSwId}\s*/) {
                push @searchResults, $line;
            }
        }
        close $fh;
    } else {
        die "error processing $file: $!";
    }
}
closedir $dh;
```

And, if you're into shell, check out the [ack](http://betterthangrep.com/) utility.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info. Will be grepping across 1000 files. When i read a 100000 lines file Each time when it comes to grep it opens the file. Is it efficient to open a file handle for each grep. where does the close file handle happen.

Comment: Thanks for an observation, @Arav! Fixed the `map{}` example so the handles are properly closed. Also added a faster iterative implementation which doesn't relies on loading everything to RAM.

Comment: If i use a Unix Grep using backtik is it going to be faster. @searchresult =`grep searchrec /tmp/testfile`.

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
use Slurp;
my $filename = 'my/file/name';
@searchResults = grep {/,\s*${searchRecId}\s*,\s*${searchSwId}\s*/}
                   slurp $filename;
```

This will read the file into memory, though.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.